# Microsoft Graph api: Filter Outlook Messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to understand the query to filter a user mailbox and find emails in a time frame and from someone and with a subject containing a keyword. This is what i was able to create but when running this i get every email i have received.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$UserUpn/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2023-07-24T00:00:00Z and from/emailAddress/address eq 'email@example.ca'&$select=receivedDateTime,Id,Sender,Subject,Body,isRead
```

This is in powershell, and $UserUpn is my user upn.

Answer (score 0):

If its powershell are you escaping the $filter and $select else what your sending through to graph will just be ignored and everything will get returned eg should be

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$UserUpn/messages?`$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2023-07-24T00:00:00Z and from/emailAddress/address eq 'email@example.ca'`&$select=receivedDateTime,Id,Sender,Subject,Body,isRead
```

I'd suggest you first try it in the Graph explorer if it work okay there but no in you script you know you it's you code thats the problem.